# Cert-manager. Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook. Wrong cert-manager hook ID

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

Try to apply issuer to kubernetes and get this error:

`Error from server (InternalError): error when creating ".\\issuer.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": Post https://cert-manager-1575287841-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=30s: service "cert-manager-1575287841-webhook" not found`

Seems it try to call this `"cert-manager-1575287841-webhook"`, but in my kubernetes i have `"cert-manager-1575353985-webhook"`.

Comment: It's most likely this bug: https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/2419

Answer (score 1):

In my case the pod was still starting:

```
cert-manager-webhook-74d98fdc7b-qmgs2      0/1     ContainerCreating   0          25m
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested on solution to this, I managed to fixed in my case, it was some cert manager k8s resource was not deleted correctly, so make sure proper clean up

remove every resource below belong to the cert manager then install fresh cert-manager

```
v1/ClusterRole
v1/Deployment
v1/Pod(related)
v1/Service
v1/ServiceAccount
v1beta1/ClusterRole
v1beta1/ClusterRoleBinding
v1beta1/MutatingWebhookConfiguration
v1beta1/Role
v1beta1/RoleBinding
v1beta1/ValidatingWebhookConfiguration
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

I also have this issue, any ideas how to fix this?

error when creating "ci.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=30s: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

this is my "ci.yaml" file:

apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    # The ACME server URL
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    # Email address used for ACME registration
    email: example@gmail.com
    # Name of a secret used to store the ACME account private key
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt
    # Enable the HTTP-01 challenge provider
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx

Version:

kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.1", GitCommit:"d224476cd0730baca2b6e357d144171ed74192d6", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-14T21:04:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.1", GitCommit:"d224476cd0730baca2b6e357d144171ed74192d6", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-01-14T20:56:50Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}